# Showing a textarea with a shortcut but without inserting the shortcut key

Tags: javascript, jquery, textarea

```
$(document).keydown(function(event) {

if(event.keyCode === 70) {
$.("#myTextarea").css('display','block');
$.('textarea').focus();
}
```

The thing is when i click **f** and the div is visible in the textarea there is letter f in it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(document).keydown(function(event) {
    if(event.keyCode === 70) {
    $.("#myTextarea").css('display','block');
    $.('textarea').focus();
    return false;
}
```

Basically you need to prevent the default event behavior by return false from the function or calling event.preventDefault().

http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$(document).keydown(function(event) {
if(event.keyCode === 70) {
$.("#myTextarea").val(" ");
$.("#myTextarea").css('display','block');
$.('textarea').focus();
}
```